# How do I add attributes to my model?

Tags: angularjs, html, model-view-controller, model, modelattribute

I have a model X, which respresents a Task.
I want to add some attributes to the model. When the do button is clicked, I want to add a "doRequested" attribute to the specific x model that was clicked. When the fund button is clicked, I want to add a specific attribute to that specific task. Also, I want to add an admin attribute set to the current user when the task was created. These attributes have to be associated with that specific task at all times so that the task "task.attributeName" will give the exact value for that attribute.

Is this kind of thing meant to be done in AngularJs? How can the $scope.todoList be modified so that for each item in todoList has both a todoText, todoAdmin:, doRequested,fundRequested attributes associated with it in the following :

```
$scope.todoList.push({todoText:$scope.todoInput, done:false});
```

As I am from Rails background, this seems too complicated and I have no idea how to .

Here is my view:

```
<div ng-app="facebookExample" view-title="Tasks">
<div ng-controller="todoController">
<h1>Tasks</h1>

 <div class="item item-input-inset">
 <label class="item-input-wrapper">
 <!-- The actual input tag which is bound to the todoInput using ng-model -->
 <input type="text" placeholder="Add New Item" ng-model="todoInput" size="100"> 
 </label>
 <!-- Our button thay will call our funtion to add a new todo item -->
<button class="button button-small" ng-click="todoAdd()">
Add Task
</button>
</div>

  <div ng-repeat="x in todoList">
  <li class="item item-checkbox">
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label class="checkbox">
  </label>
  <!-- this is the checkbox element, you will see it is bound to the done setting in the items array -->
  <!-- When clicked it calls the update function to update the item to its done status -->
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.done" ng-click="update()"/>
  <!-- this is a span tag that shows the item text, I am using ng-bind, instead of the span tag we could have used {{x.todoText}} as well -->
  <button class="fund-button" style= "float: left;" ng-click="fund(x)">Fund</button>
  <span>{{x.todoText}}</span>
  <button class="doButton" style= "float: right; margin-right: 2px;" ng-click="do(x)">Do</button>
  </li>
  </div>
  <!-- the remove button will call the remove function and remoave all items that   are marked done -->
  <button class="button button-block button-assertive" ng-click="remove()">Remove Checked Tasks
  </button>
  </div>
   </div>
```

And my controller:

```
 facebookExample.controller('todoController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
 // Initialize the todo list array
 //if local storage is null save the todolist to local storage
$scope.todoList = [];

if (localStorage.getItem("mytodos") === null)
{

 localStorage.setItem("mytodos", angular.toJson($scope.todoList));

 }else
 {
 //set the todolist from local storage
 $scope.todoList = angular.fromJson(localStorage.getItem("mytodos"));
 }


 // Add an item function
 $scope.todoAdd = function() {
 //check to see if text has been entered, if not exit
 if ($scope.todoInput === null || $scope.todoInput === ''){return;}

 //if there is text add it to the array
 $scope.todoList.push({todoText:$scope.todoInput, done:false});

 //clear the textbox
 $scope.todoInput = "";

 //resave the list to localstorage
 localStorage.setItem("mytodos", angular.toJson($scope.todoList));
 };





















  //Do button
  $scope.do = function(){

  };



 $scope.doForFree = function(x){


 };











 //fund button

 $scope.fund = function(x){

 };
  $scope.remove = function() {
  //copy list
  var oldList = $scope.todoList;
  //clear list
  $scope.todoList = [];
  //cycle through list
  angular.forEach(oldList, function(x) {
  //add any non-done items to todo list
    if (!x.done) $scope.todoList.push(x);
 });
 //update local storage
 localStorage.setItem("mytodos", angular.toJson($scope.todoList));

};

//The Update function
//This waits 100ms to store the data in local storage
$scope.update = function() {
//update local storage 100 ms after the checkbox is clicked to allow it to     process
setTimeout(function(){
 localStorage.setItem("mytodos", angular.toJson($scope.todoList));
 },100);


};

}]);
```

Comment: Don't think Angular too much, that's still JavaScript and you can just add properties to your object. If you want help you should simplify your code down to a simple example of what you'd like to do - remove anything that we don't need

Comment: I cannot understand which is your problem. Why don't you add the properties you want to the scope inside those functions. For example, in fund you could add a specific attribute to that specific task as you want.

Comment: @floribon is right, don't over complicate the code. You can easily add properties and extend your model.

Comment: If you model is an object, just do it like x.doRequest = true, thats fine. Any new member will be added to x automatically

Comment: Thank you guys I got it now